PyInstaller inputs gets glitched (repeats input, doesn't move forward)
I'm doing a small program so I tried in python to practice, and now that it all works I want to make a .exe for the client. I thought it should be easy with PyInstaller, but it bugs the input and I don't know how to find the issue....
Here is the bugged console:

Here is the input in the code:
import sys
import multiprocessing
import xlwt
from xlwt import Workbook
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os


def main():
    days_from_today = int(input("First input: "))
    days_in_the_future = int(input("Second input: "))

Here is the pyinstaller command:
C:\Users\Fernando\Desktop>python -m PyInstaller --onefile --console "scraping and excel.py"
927 INFO: PyInstaller: 6.11.1, contrib hooks: 2024.11
927 INFO: Python: 3.13.1
942 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
...
22020 INFO: Copying icon to EXE
22063 INFO: Copying 0 resources to EXE
22063 INFO: Embedding manifest in EXE
22101 INFO: Appending PKG archive to EXE
22122 INFO: Fixing EXE headers
24195 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.

What should I try?

This code as posted shouldn't even run because main is called before it's been defined. Make sure you're running the code that you think you are.

... It's a snippet of code to show how I made the inputs and how it doesn't make any sense it's showing that console output..... as I said, the code works perfectly.
